# Selenium Webdriver. Error 'org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium Webdriver + java.
My code:

```
public List<UserData> getUsers() {
        List<UserData> users = new ArrayList<UserData>();
        WebElement userList = driver.findElement(By.id("Users"));
        isElementDisplayed(By.xpath("//table[@id='Users']/*/tr[position() > 1]"), 10);
        List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='Users']/*/tr[position() > 1]"));
        for (WebElement tableRow : tableRows) {     
            List<WebElement> cells  = tableRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            UserData user = new UserData();
            user.fio = cells.get(2).getText();
            user.login = cells.get(3).getText();
            user.rank = cells.get(4).getText();
            user.cabinet = cells.get(5).getText();
            users.add(user);
            }       
        return users;
```

}

After I delete user from the table, method throws:

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no
>   longer valid

here:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='Users']/*/tr[position() > 1]"));
```

How can I fix this error, without refreshing the page?

**Please note!** 
This is not

```
Element is no longer attached to the DOM
```

error

Comment: What is the function `isElementDisplayed(by, int)` doing ?

Comment: I have a feeling that the error is related to the line above the one which you specify in your code, where you call `isElementDisplayed`. Please provide the code of this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that deleting the user rebuilds part of the DOM via JavaScript. Therefore, although the page has not reloaded, the html has changed, resulting in Selenium throwing a Stale Element. If the html is rebuilt, Selenium says all previously found elements are now stale and must be refound.

this occurs even if the original element is still in the newly refreshed DOM. If it has been rebuilt Selenium thinks it is better to be safe then sorry and therefore invalidate everything.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem partly. 
In line:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='Users']/*/tr[position() > 1]"));
```

i used my method waitForStableElements

```
...
List<WebElement> tableRows = waitForStableElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='Users']/*/tr[position() > 1]"));
...
        public List<WebElement> waitForStableElements(final By locator) {
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(new ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>>(){
              public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver d) {
                try {
                  return d.findElements(locator);
                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
                  return null;
                }
              }
            });
          }
```

It works fine. 
But 'StaleElementReferenceException' error is thrown anyway in line:

```
...
List<WebElement> cells  = tableRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
...
```

Anyway I have to refresh the page after deleting the user. 
Hope this could help somebody solving similar problem. 
Thanks for answers! ;)